# "start to be built" or "be started to build" which is grammatically correct?

Tags: passive-voice

Which is grammatically correct, "The castle started **to be** built" or "The castle **was started** to build"?

Comment: What is your own preferred option, and why?

Answer (score 1):

The first one sounds correct. It uses [the passive infinitive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-and-imperatives/infinitive-active-or-passive), which is a grammatically correct way to rephrase "They started to build the castle." The second sentence, "the castle was started", looks as if it is [passive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive/passive), and inverting it back to active results in something like "They started the castle" which does not sound right. You can see the links provided for more examples of passive and passive infinitive.

However, do you need to use passive like that in the first place? From the stylistic point of view, "They started to build the castle" is more straightforward. If, however, your writing is formal and you do not want to emphasize the subject ("they"), the focus of your sentence should be on the action, the construction of the castle. In this case, you may use something like "The construction of the castle began."